# Why is my array being passed with an incorrect size?

Tags: c++, arrays, pass-by-reference, implicit-conversion, pass-by-value

I am just starting to learn C++ and I was playing around with functions. I am trying to pass an integer array as a parameter, and have the function print every element of the array. My issue however is that I have an array initialized to a seize of 10, but when I pass it to the function it only reads it as a size of 2. Any help would be appreciated! You can find my program below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

void Max(int Arr[])
{
    for (int i=0; i<sizeof(Arr)/sizeof(Arr[0]); i++)
    {
        cout<< Arr[i]<<endl;
    }
}


int main()
{
    int Arr[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

    Max(Arr);

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you all for the help in advance!

Comment: Yes, but now I am receiving errors when I use std::vector<int> Arr={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}; instead of what I already had. it says "mplicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >'"

Comment: `Arr` decays to a pointer, so the compiler will evaluate that to `sizeof(int*)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an array is passed by value it is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element.

On the other hand a function parameter declared as having an array type is adjusted by the compiler to pointer to the array element type.

So for example these function declarations

```
void Max(int Arr[]);
void Max(int Arr[1])
void Max(int Arr[10])
void Max(int Arr[100]);
```

declare the same function and are adjusted by the compiler to the declaration

```
void Max( int *Arr );
```

As a result within the function the parameter Arr is a pointer and this expression

```
sizeof(Arr)/sizeof(Arr[0])
```

is equivalent to

```
sizeof( int * ) / sizeof( int )
```

that yields either 1 or 2 depending on the size of the type `int *`.

When you passing an array by value to a function you should also pass its size explicitly.

So the function could be defined like

```
void Max( const int Arr[], size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        cout << Arr[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

And the function can be called like

```
Max(Arr, sizeof( Arr ) / sizeof( *Arr ) );
```

Another approach is to declare the function parameter as having a referenced type. In this case it is better to use a template function that it could be called for an array at least of any size.

```
template <size_t N>
void Max( const int ( &Arr )[N] )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        cout << Arr[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Or the function could be defined like

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
void Max( const T ( &Arr )[N] )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        cout << Arr[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

And the both functions can be called like

```
Max(Arr);
```

Pay attention to that you could use the standard class template `std::array` declared in the header `<array>`. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

const size_t N = 10;

std::ostream & Max( const std::array<int, N> &a, std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
    for ( const auto &item : a )
    {
        os << item << ' ';
    }

    return os;
}


int main()
{
    std::array<int, N> a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    Max( a ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: It might be a simpler idea to use a `std::vector`, `std::list`, or a `std::deque`.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa There is no any reason to use for example std::vector or std::list if you need just an array.

Comment: You're right, `std::array` will also work. I just object to having possibly hundreds of (template) functions for arrays of different sizes.

Answer (score 1):

`void Max(int Arr[])` is equal to `void Max(int* Arr)`. 
In function `Max(int Arr[])`:
`sizeof(Arr)/sizeof(Arr[0])` = `sizeof(int*)/sizeof(int)`
On x64 it is equal 2, on x86 it is equal 1

correct your code:
---------------------------------

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>

    using namespace std;

    void Max(int Arr[], int len)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
        {
            cout<< Arr[i]<<endl;
        }
    }


    int main()
    {
        int Arr[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

        Max(Arr, sizeof(Arr)/sizeof(Arr[0]));

        return 0;
    }
```